# Cakephp use Variables from Vendor php file

Tags: variables, cakephp, include, vendor

I've imported a selfwritten PHP Vendor file in Cakephp 2.X like this

**View: XXX.ctp:**

```
App::import('Vendor', 'languages', array('file' => 'variables/toUse.php'));
```

In this file I've declared some variables like this, in order to use them in the view:

**toUse.php:**

```
$test = 'Placeholder';
$anotherTest = 'anotherPlaceholder';
```

but unfortunately I can't use the variable in my view:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: test [APP/View/XXX/XXX.ctp, line X]
```

But for example a Debugger::dump() inside my toUse.php is displayed correctly in my view XXX.ctp..

So my Question is, is it not possible to use variables from the imported vendor files, or do I've made something wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting variables in a Vendor file? Would you not be better setting them in the Controller (*i.e.* the Cake way)?

Comment: I use them in several views, and they are constants. So if i need to adjust one, i have to modify it in every controller. So with this approach i want to save pains by just modifying it once in the vendor file

Comment: That's not a good design. For what you describe - you should be using [the configure class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class), not vendor files (if you want to know why it doesn't work - look at [the scope in which the file is required](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Core/App.php#L763) - variables defined inside a function aren't accessible outside it). It's the basis for [all configuration in CakePHP apps](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/app/Config/core.php#L34)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to set your variables in the Controller. If these need to be accessible by multiple controllers (as suggested in your comment) then you can do this in the `beforeRender()` callback of `AppController`:-

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->set('test', 'Placeholder');
    $this->set('anotherTest', 'anotherPlaceholder');
}
```

You can then use these as normal in your View templates:-

```
echo $test;
```

Vendor files shouldn't really be used for setting data for a View.

Answer (score 1):

You could inside your file write a function to return this variable and then inside your view call this function. In your case inside **toUse** file:

```
function getVariable(){
    $var = 1;
    return $var;
}
```

and then inside your view file

```
App::import('Vendor', 'languages', array('file' => 'variables/toUse.php'));
$x = getVariable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define them in your AppController.php, and pass them to the view there.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4260264/5036487